# How to add a subscriber in wordpress with a request

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning all
I would like to add a new subscriber in the wordpress database with a request placed on a php page independent of wordpress

But I have two problems

the first with the date it indicates that 0

and I have an error with the "" at the subscriber level

```
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // affichera 18 09 2003 20:21
$a =date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    include('base2.php');
    $essai=$a;
                                       $sql = "INSERT INTO `u4_testclone`.`wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`,`user_url`,`user_registered`, `user_activation_key`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('312', 'demo', MD5('demo'), 'Your Name', 'phil@pecheperle.be', 'http://www.example.com/', $essai , '', '0', 'Your Name');" ;
                                       // On prépare la requête
                                       $query = $bdd->prepare($sql);
                                       // On exécute
                                       $query->execute();
                                       ?>

<?php                                            
  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `u4_testclone`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '3', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}');" ;
                                       // On prépare la requête
                                       $query = $bdd->prepare($sql2);
                                       // On exécute
                                       $query->execute();
                                       ?>


                                       
<?php
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `u4_testclone`.`wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '3', 'wp_user_level', '10');" ;
                                       // On prépare la requête
                                       $query = $bdd->prepare($sql);
                                       // On exécute
                                       $query->execute();
                                       ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you try to create user to the database?
You can use wp_create_user function.

```php
wp_create_user('demo', 'demo', 'phil@pecheperle.be' );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Because I want to do it in a php page in a subdomain reread in php

Comment: You can include wp-config.php from wordpress and to use all the functions.